# Load Toolbar of AppBar dynamically based on current page - React Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I am relatively new to the React world and struggling to find a way to load IconButtons to the toolBar of an AppBar (from Material UI).

Say I am on pageA and like to have two IconButtons specific to pageA and when I got to pageB, I like to have the toolBar buttons loaded that are specific to pageB.

I have created a codesandbox project to make it easier for anyone to help.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui--react-admin-1qc5x

I appreciate any help, guidance etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by multiple ways:

1. Redux: you can use `react-redux` and create a `store` where you can store your `current_page` value (best practice in case of SPA) and access the page value in

   `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    //your code here 
   }`
2. Based on Route(`react-router`)
3. [what i have done] based on `URL params` as you are doing `history.push` so it will be easier to extract the params from your URL and based on that render your Toolbar Icons.

My code reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui--react-admin-nxh7m